# Get IP of ansible mongo module

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm writing an ansible role to install mongodb. But i need to do the replication part. In order to do the replication, How can i get the each ip address of each ec2 instance.

**Note:**There are 4 ec2 instances which spin up by terraform. Therefore i cannot hard code the ip's in hosts file.

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Ansible
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_ec2_local_ipv4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
  roles:
    - role: "ansible-mongo/roles/mongo"`
```

[Please find the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQT7.png)

Comment: You have failed to specify any steps you have already taken toward this problem, or any errors you are encountering with existing tries

Comment: I want to get the IP's of each host. That's why i ask for the help. I have followed this https://github.com/UnderGreen/ansible-role-mongodb

Comment: You have failed to specify any **steps you have already taken** toward this problem; I didn't say "why do you want help". Just like we are not psychic, the computer is not psychic -- you will need a means to enumerate the hosts -- do you have ec2 instance-ids? do you have dns names? do you have them on a post-it from your cousin?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ansible Dynamic Inventory. but you have fail to specify your question properly.